# Why is Fortran slower than Octave?

Tags: fortran, octave

Normally, Fortran is leaps and bounds faster than Octave.  However, I've noticed that when performing similar matrix manipulations with Fortran's "spread" function, compared to Octave's "repmat" function, Octave runs about twice as fast as my compiled Fortran version of the program.  Is anyone able to give an explanation as to why that is?  Is there something that I need to be doing in order to increase Fortran's performance?

First, here's my simple fortran program:

```
program test_program
    double precision, parameter, dimension(1000,500) :: A = reshape([ ... ],[1000,500])
    logical, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: blockL
    integer, dimension(2) :: Adim

    Adim = shape(A)
    blockL = spread(A,3,Adim(1))==spread(transpose(A),1,Adim(1))
end program test_program
```

Now here's my corresponding program, written in Octave:

```
A = [ ... ];  % This is the same "A" that was used in Fortran
Adim1 = size(A,1);
blockL = repmat(A,[1 1 Adim1])==repmat(permute(A,[3 2 1]),[Adim1 1 1]);
```

Once compiled, the Fortran program takes about fifteen seconds to run.  The Octave program takes about eight.  Shouldn't a compiled program always be faster than an interpreted one?  Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong, or how I could speed up my Fortran program?

I'm using the gfortran compiler on a machine that is running Lubuntu 14.04.  The following shows exactly how I'm compiling it, when I type my command at the Linux console:

`gfortran test_program.f08 -o test_program`

I have Octave installed on the same machine, so both programs are using the same resources and hardware when being compared.

Thanks so much for your time and attention.  I appreciate any guidance that anyone is able, or willing, to provide.

Comment: In theory interpreted can at times be faster due to the ability to inline code instead of loop.  There was an academic/PHD paper some time ago on the subject but I don't have the reference to it.

it might help if you included more details such as the platform, compiler etc. as this is not as mainstream as many other subject matter topics like HTML

Comment: Are you enabling optimizations when compiling the Fortran code? Note that Octave adds overhead for each statement, but in this case it’s a single statement that takes all the computation time, so Octave’s overhead is negligible.

Comment: By the way, you can do the same thing in Octave without `repmat`, and it’ll be even faster!

Comment: Your Fortran code does not make sense.  The assignment involving `BlockL` appears to be assigning the result of a rational operation to a double precision variable.

Comment: @evets - do you mean "logical" rather than "rational"? If so I agree. And if this is a simple program I'd hate to see a complicated one!

Comment: Fortran is never fast or slow.  Fortran is a language. Implementations may compile faster or slower running code. So you must always tell **which compiler** with **which options** you are using.  But here te compiling is probably not that important.  You are just calling a library function. One has to check how that function is implemented in the runtime library your compiler is using and in the Octave runtime library.

Comment: @Ian Bush, I mean the result of a rational intrinsic operation (10.1.5.5).  The result is of course `logical`.

Comment: Good catch, @events.  You're right, 'blockL' is type "logical".  I ran this program on a machine that is different from the one that I'm using now to post my question.  I made a mistake when re-typing it, and have since corrected my mistake by editing my post.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I've updated my question to also show that I'm using the gfortran compiler on a Linux machine that is running Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Fladimir F, you make an interesting point.  It makes me wonder what Octave is doing that my compiler isn't.  Listening to some of these responses makes me rethink how an interpreted language, like Octave, works.  Perhaps, when building their functions, Octave used some sort of optimization that I'm not using with gfortran.  Please forgive me if I sound a little uneducated when it comes to this aspect of programming.  Most of my experience has been centered around learning these programming languages without giving much thought to how these functions execute what I'm programming.

Comment: Thanks, @Cris Luengo.  I don't see how I would be able to make all of the comparisons in the Octave program without replicating "A".  Do you mean that Octave has a more efficient function, or way, of building the replicated "A" matrix?  Thanks to all of you for your valuable input.

Comment: In Octave, any operation (including the equality comparison) between a row vector and a column vector yields a matrix. The operation implicitly expands the arrays where a dimension has size 1 to the size of the corresponding dimension in the other operand. Basically, it applies your `repmat` without physically copying the array and using all that memory.

Comment: You certainly should use optimizations when compiling Fortran for good performance. Try -O3.

Comment: @Chris, I'm aware of what you're talking about, and I can see how that would work if I were comparing an array, or a matrix, to a single value (aka A==A(1,1), for example).  But in my case, I'm doing row-by-row comparisons of a matrix.  I can see how repmat could be eliminated if I used a loop.  Something like: for n=1:Adim1; blockL(n,:,:) = A==A(n,:); end.  However, I'm trying to avoid loops.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir.  I'll certainly give that a try and see if it speeds things up.

Comment: @Chris, I stand corrected.  The following seems to also work: blockL = A==permute(A,[3 2 1]).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out, in the comments section, interpreted languages, like Octave, are only slow based on the number of lines, or command calls, that exist in your program.  When it comes to intrinsic functions, Octave can be relatively fast.

As for building a Fortran program that is as fast as the Octave version, I ultimately turned to coarrays.

Fortran's coarray feature is an excellent way for programmers to exploit the benefits of multi-processor computers.  Octave uses optimized tools, similar to tools like BLAS, in their implementation.  Those tools are also capable of exploiting the parallel nature of processors by using SIMD features of modern processors.  Although I'm not completely sure that coarrays use that exact implementation, on the processor level (they probably do), they do allow programmers to include parallelization in their programs.

By using coarrays, I was able to write a program that is as fast as the fastest Octave version of my program; maybe even faster.

One commenter suggested compiling my original Fortran program using the "-O3" optimization option with gfortran.  In my case, doing so resulted in no speed increase.